# What does set command without arguments do?

Tags: bash, set

What does `set` command without arguments do?

As I can see it prints out my environment variables just like `env` command but in alphabetical order. And further it prints some different information (variables? functions?) like:

```
__git_printf_supports_v=yes
__grub_script_check_program=grub-script-check
...
quote () 
{ 
    local quoted=${1//\'/\'\\\'\'};
    printf "'%s'" "$quoted"
}
quote_readline () 
{ 
    local quoted;
    _quote_readline_by_ref "$1" ret;
    printf %s "$ret"
}
```

**What is it and where does it come from?**

I cannot find information about `set` command without arguments. Actually I don't have a `man` page for `set` in my Linux distribution at all.

Comment: "This builtin is so complicated that it deserves its own section."  See [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`set` is a shell built-in that displays all shell variables, not only the environment ones, and also shell functions, which is what you are seeing at the end of the list.

Variables are displayed with a syntax that allow them to be set when the lines are executed or sourced.

From `bash` [manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin):

> *If no options or arguments are supplied, set displays the names and values of all shell variables and functions, sorted according to the current locale, in a format that may be reused as input for setting or resetting the currently-set variables.*

On different shells, the behavior is not necessarily the same; for example, `ksh` `set` doesn't display shell functions.

Comment: That's because `ksh` do not store function definition in shell variable.

Comment: @cuonglm A wise design decision made by dgk! ;-)

Answer (score 10):

[`set` is a shell builtin](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_25), used to set and unset shell options and positional parameters.

Without arguments, `set` will print all shell variables (both environment variables and variables in current session) sorted in current [locale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html#tag_07).

You can also read [bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-set).

---

There're a few caveats.

`set "$var"` will assign `var` value to `$1`. If `$var` starts with `-` or `+`, then `$var` content will be treated as sequences of shell options. If `$var` contains any invalid options, most POSIX shells will print the error. `yash` and `zsh` in `sh`, `ksh` emulation are not only printing the error, but also setting valid options. While `yash` stops setting options on the first invalid option, `zsh` will assign all of them. In `yash`:

```
var=-fxd; set "$var"
```

`f` and `x` will be present in `$-`, while:

```
var=fdx; set "$var"
```

only `f` is present in `$-`. In both cases, `f` and `x` will be present in `$-` with `zsh` in `sh` and `ksh` emulation.

To protect you from that situation, you can pass `--` as the first argument to set a positional parameter even if it starts with `-` or `+`:

```
var=-fdx; set -- "$var"
```

will assign `$var` to `$1`, regardless of its content.

`set --` without any further arguments will unset all positional parameters.

If the first argument is `-`, the behavior is unspecified. All known POSIX shells will unset `x` and `v` options (except `posh`), and assign anything after `-` to positional parameters:

```
set -xv - -f
```

will assign `-f` to `$1`. `set -` also did not unset positional parameters. [Schily osh](http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/bosh.html) also behaves like that. [Heirloom sh](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh.html) does not unset `v` and `x` options.

The only POSIX shell exception is `yash`, which treats `-` as the first positional parameter:

```
$ yash -c 'set -xv - -f; printf "%s\n" "$@"; printf "%s\n" "$-"'
+ printf %s\n - -f
-
-f
+ printf %s\n cvx
cvx
```

[Schily sh](http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/bosh.html) even doing nothing if `-` is present in arguments:

```
$ schily-sh -c 'set -v - -f; printf "%s\n" "$@"; printf "%s\n" "$-"'
<blank line>
s

$ schily-sh -c 'set -v -- -f; printf "%s\n" "$@"; printf "%s\n" "$-"'
-f
vs
```

Comment: i never understand why people would link to anywhere but the first one... you might like to mention the different between `set -- $unset`, `set - $unset`, `set $unset`, and `set "$unset"` and so on - it's usually those discrepancies that get people into that kind of trouble in the first place.

Comment: @mikeserv: Well, I added further details, but I didn't got what do you mean when used `$unset`.

Comment: @cuonglm The command `set $unset` will act exactly equal as `set` for an unset variable. But `set "$unset"`  will do noting, if `unset` is actually an unset variable. A `set - $unset` removes the `-v` and `-x` set options (in bash).

Comment: @BinaryZebra: Ah, of course, for me, it's better to use `unset_var`. And also note that `set "$unset"` is actually set `$1` to empty. That's about shell expansion, not strictly to `set`, so I don't mention it.

Comment: @mikeserv: Ah right, updated answer. Actually, I mean in case of treating arguments after `-`.

Comment: @mikeserv: The behavior of `posh` and `yash` are different when `-` appear. You can read my updated (and feel free to improve it).

Comment: yeah - `yash` is a wildcard.

Answer (score 8):

Because `set` has output and `which set` returns nothing you know it's part of the shell you are using, likely bash.

[man bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) mentions it many times but it's easier to link to in the [online documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-set).

> This builtin is so complicated that it deserves its own section. set
>   allows you to change the values of shell options and set the
>   positional parameters, or to display the names and values of shell
>   variables.

set has the call specification of:

```
set [--abefhkmnptuvxBCEHPT] [-o option-name] [argument …]
set [+abefhkmnptuvxBCEHPT] [+o option-name] [argument …]
```

so if you want to find it in man on the command line you can search with

```
/set.*abef
```

Comment: `which set` depends on your shell. At least `zsh` will report it for you. You can also read [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/38906) for more details.

Comment: It's unlikely the question is about anything but bash as it has a large market dominance, and anyone using the non default shell would not need to ask this question.

Answer (score 3):

If you are working inside a bash shell, type `help set`.

At the end of the help printed, read:

> If no ARGs are given, all shell variables are printed.

So, a no arguments `set` prints all variables known to the shell.

Comment: I wonder if `set -x; set` would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot find information about set command without arguments. Actually I don't have a man page for set in my Linux distribution at all.

Actually since `set` is builtin bash itself, you have access bash's help manual instead of man page. For that you can use `help` or in this case `help set`.

Comment: This appears to have been covered by other answers already.